# Ignore case sensitivity when comparing strings in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare words for equality, and the case [upper and lower] is irrelevant.
However PHP does not seem to agree! Any ideas as to how to force PHP to ignore the case of words while comparing them?

```
$arr_query_words = ["hat","Cat","sAt","maT"];
for( $j= 0; $j < count($arr_query_words); $j++ ){
    $story_body = str_replace( 
        $arr_query_words[ $j ],
        '<span style=" background-color:yellow; ">' . $arr_query_words[ $j ] . '</span>',
        $story_body
   );
}
```

Is there a way to carry out the replace even if the case is different?

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully answer what you were trying to ask!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use [`str_ireplace`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) to perform a case-insensitive string replacement (`str_ireplace` is available from PHP 5):

```
$story_body = str_ireplace($arr_query_words[$j],
   '<span style=" background-color:yellow; ">'. $arr_query_words[$j]. '</span>',
    $story_body);
```

To case-insensitively compare strings, use [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp):

```
<?php
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "hello";
if (strcasecmp($var1, $var2) == 0) {
    echo '$var1 is equal to $var2 in a case-insensitive string comparison';
}
?>
```

Comment: Good to know :)

I have always been doing strtolower($var1) == strtolower($var2) to do case insensitive comparison

Comment: Exactly how I'd do it.  For regular string comparison I always use it's case sensitive brother 'strcmp' you can never be too careful with PHP's loose typing.

Comment: Depending on what you are comparing you might want to add a trim to clear trailing whitespace.

    if(strcasecmp(trim($var1), trim($var2)) == 0) {}

Comment: If you are going to do strtolower method, use strcmp(mb_strtolower($var1), mb_strtolower($var2)) to take in consideration multi-byte strings.

Answer (score 31):

The easiest, and most widely supported way to achieve this is possibly to lowercase both strings before comparing them, like so:

```
if(strtolower($var1) == strtolower($var2)) {
    // Equals, case ignored
}
```

You might want to trim the strings being compared, simply use something like this to achieve this functionality:

```
if(strtolower(trim($var1)) == strtolower(trim($var2))) {
    // Equals, case ignored and values trimmed
}
```

Comment: the strtolower method is very common, and the trim suggestion is definitely useful, thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
$var1 = "THIS is A teST";
$var2 = "this is a tesT";
if (strtolower($var1) === strtolower($var2) ) {
    echo "var1 and var2 are same";
}
```

`strtolower` converts string to lowercase

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!strcasecmp($str1, $str2)) ... //they are equals ignoring case
```

strcasecmp returns 0 only if strings are equals ignoring case, so !strcasecmp return true if they are equals ignoring case, false otherwise

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Comment: maybe some purist don't like !0 and prefer !=0, I'm not one of them and prefer smaller code :D